# Proof that a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is the identity coset in the group of cosets of $N$

Tags: group-theory

I am not sure how to prove the following:

Let $N$ be a group. Prove that for any $n\in N, nN=N$.

(Or maybe the following, but I'm not sure it's correct: $n\in N$ $\Leftrightarrow nN = N$)

I haven't been asked to prove this directly, but I seem to run into many proofs that require the above, yet don't bother to do any explanation regarding it (So I assumed the above fact is trivial).

Any guidance/explanation would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have changed the title, which may now be wrong, since it does not quite reflect the excellent answers you have. But you did mention the "identity" and this works as $aNbN=abNb^{-1}bN$ ($N$ is normal) and then if $b \in N$ this is equal to $aN$ by the result you are looking for. And a similar argument works for $bNaN$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formulation is the following.

> Suppose $N$ is a subgroup of the group $G$. Let $g \in G$. Then $g N = N$ if and only if $g \in N$.

You should know that for two cosets one has
$$ \text{$a N = b N$ if and only if $a^{-1} b \in N$.}\tag{fact}$$ So $N = 1 N = g N$ if and only if $1^{-1} g = g \in N$.

To prove (fact), you may start from the relation $R$ on $G$ defined by $a R b$ if and only if $a^{-1} b \in N$. You can prove this is an equivalence relation, and the class of an element $g$ is $g N$.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I've missed this.

Comment: @Py42, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in nN$ then $x=ny$ for some $y\in N$. As $N$ is a subgroup, $n\in N, y\in N$ implies $a\in N$. Hence $nN\subseteq N$.

If $x\in N$, then $y:=n^{-1}x\in N$ because $N$ is a group. Hence $x=ny\in nN$ and also $N\subseteq nN$.

So, yes, it's really quite immediate from the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in N$. For any $m\in N$ there exists $n^{-1}m\in N$.

So $n\cdot n^{-1}m\in nN$. But $n\cdot n^{-1}m=m$, so $m\in nN$ for any $m\in N$.

Thus $N\subset nN$, but also $nN\subset N$, so $N=nN$.